# How to disable alert message from s2member plugin in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, validation, wordpress

I am new at wordpress. I am using s2member plugin for the registration of users. Whenever users fails to meet the required condition s2member plugin validate entries and displays the error via alert. I want to disable that alert. How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this plugin is open source so you may not be able to modify its source code. If it isn't and if it doesn't have any option to disable the alerts then you're out of luck.

But if it is ok for you to disable all alerts on the page and not only those generated but this particular plugin, then you may be able to do that by adding:

```
window.alert = function () {};
```

to some script that is loaded before that plugin's JavaScript code.

If you can edit the HTML code of your templates then you may be able to add:

```
<script>
  window.alert = function () {};
</script>
```

somewhere high on the page, like in the beginning of the `<head>` and disable all alerts on that page this way.